# Trying to put a copy/clone/duplicant of a class in a List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with a class which derives from MonoBehavior and is attached to a GameObject. When this GameObject("the projectile") collides with something, the component "Effect" should be duped and stored in a List() on the hitted target. After the assignment the projectile should be destroyed.

When i run this, i see in the List only "Missing (Effect)". I guess i assign just a reference into the list, and when the projectile gets deleted the reference is getting lost.

Projectile GameObject has Effect and Projectile classes as components attached:

```
public class Effect : MonoBehaviour {
    public float dps = 2f;
    public float duration = 2f;
    public operatingDelay = 0.1f;
    public bool freezing = false;

    void Start(){
         StartCoroutine("DamageHealRoutine");
    }

    IEnumerator DamageHealRoutine() {
        int goalCount = (int)(duration / operatingDelay);
        float partialDamage = dps * operatingDelay;
        for (int i = 0; i < goalCount; i++) {
            if (dps > 0)
                stats.TakeDamage(partialDamage);
            else if (dps < 0)
                stats.GetHeal(partialDamage);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(operatingDelay);
        }

    }
}

public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour {
    public Effect effect;

    private void Awake() {
        effect = GetComponent<Effect>(); // not null
    }

    public void hittedSomething(GameObject go) {
        go.GetComponent<Stats>().effects.Add(effect);
        // Without destroying, the List entry is assinged accordingly.
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        //Became Missing when destroying the Projectile
        }
    }
```

Target GameObject has the stats class as component attached:

```
public class Stats : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<Effect> effects;
}
```

Effect has to a inheritor from MonoBehavior, because it should be able to start Coroutines and i want to alter it's values.

Is there a possibility to achieve this without adding the Effect as a component on the target?

Edit1:
[Missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaeE7.png)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. *"Effect has to a inheritor from MonoBehavior, because it should be able to start Coroutines and i want to alter it's values"* Can you include the coroutine part?

Comment: what is effect in projectile? is it a prefab reference? is it a child? or one object among many other effects like in a pool?

Comment: @Programmer Added the coroutine part.

Comment: @Bijan Effect is a component on the Projectile. I want the dps(damage per second) be ajustable for having different Projectile types.

Comment: well you are destroying the game object so all its components are destroyed. that's why it's missing

Comment: @Bijan I know. I want to know, if i somehow can get an independant clone of this component without attaching it somewhere else.

Comment: why not creating a separate gameobject for effect? does it have to be a sibling of projectile?

Comment: @Bijan I dont want to spam the hierarchy with lots of empties. The effect will take some effect for a fixed duration and then will getting deleted. If i had to create a gameObject to attach it, i have to instatiate it, reparent, wait and afterwards delete it. And this is just to much. :)

Comment: @Vala.D. that would be another problem and its solution is object pooling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Effect has to a inheritor from MonoBehavior, because it should be able
>   to start Coroutines and i want to alter it's values.
>
> Is there a possibility to achieve this without adding the Effect as a
>   component on the target?

**Yes**. You simply need a reference of **any** `MonoBehaviour` from any script you are 100% sure that won't be destroyed. I said this because if they are destroyed, the coroutine may stop running.

In this example I will get the reference from `Stats` script but you can get it from any script you wish.

New `Stats` script script:

```
public class Stats : MonoBehaviour
{

    public List<Effect> effects;
    private MonoBehaviour mono;

    public MonoBehaviour monoRef
    {
        get
        {
            return mono;
        }
    }


    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake()
    {
        mono = this;
    }
}
```

New `Effect` script. No MonoBehaviour required:

```
public class Effect
{

    public float dps = 2f;
    public float duration = 2f;
    public operatingDelay = 0.1f;
    public bool freezing = false;

    MonoBehaviour coroutineMono;

    public Effect()
    {

        coroutineMono = GameObject.Find("StatsObj").GetComponent<Stats>().monoRef;
        coroutineMono.StartCoroutine("DamageHealRoutine");
    }

    IEnumerator DamageHealRoutine()
    {
        int goalCount = (int)(duration / operatingDelay);
        float partialDamage = dps * operatingDelay;
        for (int i = 0; i < goalCount; i++)
        {
            if (dps > 0)
                stats.TakeDamage(partialDamage);
            else if (dps < 0)
                stats.GetHeal(partialDamage);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(operatingDelay);
        }
    }
}
```

You should now use `Effect effect  = new Effect ()` and it will start the coroutine without `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now i can't change the dps on the Effect in the inspector.

Comment: If script does not inherit from MonoBehaviour, the variables won't appear in the Editor. That's one of the trade off but it's worth it if that's the only issue.

Comment: Made Effect.cs inherit from ScriptableObject and started the coroutine on the Stats.cs everything works now like a charm. Thanks a lot!